# Spring current user as Hateoas resource

Tags: spring, security, hateoas

It's my first Spring project. I have a user repository exposed as a RepositoryRestResource. And I have Spring Security set up for very basic authentication. What I would like to do is to return the current user's Hateoas resource from my AuthenticationController without having to maintain a resource assembler. I want to consume the user RepositoryRestResource from inside the AuthenticationController and return the resource as it is. Right now, I have something like this:

```
@RestController
public class AuthenticationController {

    @RequestMapping("/user")
    public Principal user(Principal user) {
        return user;
    }
}
```

I can get the User entity from the principal or with something like:

```
Resource<User> getCurrentUser(@ModelAttribute User self){...}
```

And I want to return the user's Hateoas resource instead of the Principal by reaching the repository rest resource from the controller. How can I achieve this or is it a weird thing to ask for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retrieve your user entity from the repository using your principal details, for example:

```
@BasePathAwareController
public class MyUserController {

  @Autowired UserAccountRepository repository;

  @GetMapping("/user")
  @ResponseBody
  public Resource<?> getUser(@AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetails principal, PersistentEntityResourceAssembler assembler) {

    if (null==principal) {
      return null;
    }

    UserAccount user = repository.findByUsername(principal.getUsername());
    return assembler.toFullResource(user);
  }
}
```

Notes:

- `@BasePathAwareController` - Replaces standard controller annotation to use base REST URI.
- See [@AuthenticationPrincipal](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/bind/annotation/AuthenticationPrincipal.html)